# is /etc/bin/hadoop a synchronous call?

Tags: hadoop, asynchronous, mapreduce, nutch

when you call /etc/bin/hadoop jar myjar.jar myclass args

Does the map reduce job run synchronousely? another words, does the call return only after all the map reduce jobs on all the nodes have completed?

This is especially relevant in case a nutch job is dispatched. I want to know whether site crawling has been completed by the time the command returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , it is a synchronous call because for the final result you have to wait till the completion of job at all the nodes. In fact I would say it also depends on how you have written the job i.e. you can add some lines of code to print your current status of crawl on terminal , by which you will get the live status update of your crawl.
But to see the final output of the crawl you have to wait till the completion of job.

Comment: Sorry for not adding to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

No, `Map Reduce` jobs not done same time.
First Mapper class finishes its work, then output of mapper will submitted to reducer phase(in between `shuffling,sorting,combing`).
In mapper phase nodes share their results to NameNode, if namenode found complete output then it will tell to mapper to stop mapper phase.
After then start reduce phase.

Comment: I believe the question isn't very clear. Of course map and reduce are done in sequence. However, the entire thing is one job. I tested out experimentally after posting. It appears that if you call job.waitForCompletion(), then the entire hadoop call will behave as a synchronous call. Anyone cares to comment?